# Ratio of Expected values of Boys to Girls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

In a country where everyone wants a boy, each family continues having babies till they have a boy. After some time, what is the proportion of boys to girls in the country? (Assuming probability of having a boy or a girl is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the expected number of girls in any given family is $g$. If a boy is born first (probability =$\frac{1}{2}$) then $g=0$, but if a girl is born (probability =$\frac{1}{2}$) then $g=1 + g$ ($1$ for the girl already born to the couple and $g$ for the fact that state is reset to original state where couple have to keep breeding until a boy is born)

$\implies$   $g = 0 (\frac{1}{2}) + (g + 1) \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies$   $g = 1$

Similarly, lets say the expected number of boys in any given family is $b$. If a boy is born (probability =$\frac{1}{2}$) then $b=1$, but if a girl is born (probability =$\frac{1}{2}$) then $b=0 + b$ ($0$ because now the newborn is girl and $b$ for the fact that couple are back to where they started but with an extra girl and couple keep breeding)

$\implies$   $b = 1 (\frac{1}{2}) + (b + 0) \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies$   $b = 1$

Lets say town has $n$ couples. Therefore, expected number of girls in town is $E[g_1] + E[g_2] + ... +E[g_n]$

But, $E[g_1] = E[g_2] = E[g_n] = g = 1$

$\implies$ Expected number of girls in town $= n$

Similarly, Expected number of boys in town $= n$

This implies ratio of expected values is $n:n = 1:1$

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. This is very helpful

Comment: @Rahul, there's a problem with this: Let the number of boys be $B$, and the number of girls be $G$.  Then the ratio is $R = B/G$.  This **does not** imply that $E[R] = E[B]/E[G]$.

Comment: @MarcusM I hear what you say and made the edit in my final line. But I assumed by ratio the question is asking $\frac{E[B]}{E[G]}$. Gerry can you make it clear in your question. Lets say if that is not the case, then I am not sure. MarcusM any suggestions?

Comment: @Rahul yes you are right. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Rahul, If that's not the case and Gerry is genuinely looking for $E[R]$, then there will be issues since $R$ will be undefined when $G = 0$.  You could alter the question to ask something like "what is the expected fraction of boys."  I think you're probably right that that's what Gerry is looking for, though.

Comment: @MarcusM thanks for raising this and now I am curious on how to approach the problem of Expected ratio. Lets say couple start with 1 boy and 1 girl (sort of Laplace correction)

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about the expected fraction of boys in the population, and let's just consider one family.  The fraction of boys is $F = \frac{B}{B + G}$.  If we follow your rule, this family will stop having children precisely when they get a boy, so $B = 1$, implying $F = 1/(1 + G)$.  Now, let's note that $$P(G = 0) = \frac{1}{2},\quad P(G=1) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
and that in general $P(G = k) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}$.  This then means that \begin{align}
E[F] &= E\left[\frac{1}{1 + G}\right] \\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + k}P(G = k) \\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1} \\
&= \log(2).
\end{align}

Dealing with more than one family is much more complicated.

Comment: Marcus, you were right, my (now deleted) answer was quite wrong.